# java webservice class including a method that return many rows and two column to display it in android activity

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services

**webservice class and method,**

```
package MyWebService;


import javax.jws.WebService;


/**
 *
* @author Dell
 */
@WebService
public class MyService {



public String my() {
    return "MY VALUE";
}
}
```

**android activity where I want to display two column name and address from mysql using ksoap jar library**

```
  package com.example.web_service;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SelectValue extends Activity {


TextView text;
Button btn;


/*private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://MyWebService/";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.56.1:8080/WebApplication1/MyServiceService?wsdl";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "my";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://MyWebService/my";*/

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://MyWebService/";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.56.1:8080/WebAppData/MyServiceService?WSDL";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "my";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://MyWebService/my";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_value);

    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

new SelectData().execute();
    /*btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new SelectData().execute();
        }
    });*/
}

/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select_value, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}*/

private class SelectData extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    String aak="";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SoapPrimitive response = null;
        try {
            response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        aak = response.toString();

        return aak;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onPostExecute(result);

        text.setText(aak);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}//end-class SelectData
}//end- classs SelectValue
```

**I want to display  mysql table containing two column and many rows.but simple string value MY VALUE is getting in the android activity but I have no idea about accessing the mysql table value in the android activity.**

Comment: any one ,who have enough experience on android ksoap library.By using ksoap I have to display list of data in android activity.Especially it is related to restaurant lunch menu.Any way I have already insert the data of the launch menu in the local mysql server from android using ksoap but I have problem in retrieving those in android app

Comment: please return webservice value so that we can use in android app